# How to manage Async in failure?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm working on one requirement where I need to consume messages from Kafka broker. The frequency is very high, so that's why I've choosen Async mechanism.

I want to know, while consuming messages, lets say connection break down with broker or broker itself failed due to any reason and offset could not get commit back to broker. So after restarting, I've to consume same messages again which was consumed earlier but not commited back in broker.

```
private static void startConsumer() {

      while (true) {
          ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
          for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
              System.out.printf("consumed: key = %s, value = %s, partition id= %s, offset = %s%n",
                      record.key(), record.value(), record.partition(), record.offset());
          }
          if (records.isEmpty()) {
              System.out.println("-- terminating consumer --");
              break;
          }
          printOffsets("before commitAsync() call", consumer, topicPartition);
          consumer.commitAsync();
          printOffsets("after commitAsync() call", consumer, topicPartition);
      }
      printOffsets("after consumer loop", consumer, topicPartition);
  }
```

may I know please, what can be done to overcome this situation where I dont need to consume same message again after restart ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage your offsets on your own in a atomic way. That means, you need build your own "transaction" around

- fetching data from Kafka,
- processing data, and
- storing processed offsets externally (or in your case printing it to the logs).

The methods commitSync and commitAsync will not get you far here as they can only ensure at-most-once or at-least-once processing within the Consumer. In addition, it is beneficial that your processing is *idempotent*.

There is a nice [blog](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-clients-at-most-once-at-least-once-exactly-o) that explains such an implementation making use of the `ConsumerRebalanceListener` and storing the offsets in your local file system. A full code example is also provided.